# Blazor project adding dependencies between projects

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor project that the project dependency will only allow one project to be added. For instance i have a dataaccess project and a models project in the same solution. When i add the models project to the dataaccess project as a dependency it allows it but when i try adding the dataaccess to the models project it won't let me and vice versa if i remove the dependency and reverse them. Is this the way it works or am i doing something wrong?

I came across this issue while working on a blazor project and just messing around with it.
Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: This is not specific to Blazor. Circular dependenices are not allowed and should not be needed. So yes, you are doing something wrong.  Models should be Db agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many dependencies as you need, but you cannot have **circular dependencies**.

If you add `Models` project into your `DataAccess`, you cannot do it vice versa.

Why?

`DataAccess` "sees" what is inside `Models`, and all the dependencies of Models, and this would go forever if you add `DataAccess` as a dependency of `Models`.

Not specific to Blazor.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Alamakanambra. Never knew there as such a thing as circular dependency. I guess this forces us to apply programming practices and avoids any errors or bad architecture design.